# Eclipse plugin to add SFTP support to be used as a remote editor

Tags: eclipse, sftp

I am looking for an Eclipse plugin that

- adds SFTP support and allow using private keys
- whenever the user save a file it would get uploaded on the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [*Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime* Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944100/395857) plugin:

- free and open-source
- adds SFTP support and allow using private keys:
  You just need to add your private key in the following configuration window (and in the login window you can leave the password blank or put any random password as the private key will be used to connect anyway):

[image]

- whenever the user save a file it would get uploaded on the server:

[image]

It's great to use along with [SuperPuTTY](https://code.google.com/p/superputty/):

[image]

or you can launch a shell from Eclipse:

[image]

[image]