# Real Time View of HTML/CSS/Java/Python

Tags: javascript, html, python, css

I am looking for an editor that can show me real time views of HTML, CSS, Python and Java so I can edit my code and see the changes as I go.  Is there any such program?  Uploading the rewritten code to a web server every time is a pain.

Comment: You should probably just create and run a local server when you're developing and run them from there.

Comment: Related Keyword: Live Reload

Comment: I just give an editor that meets your requirement (partial). I said partial because this editor supports live-preview what you are doing with the source code for HTML and CSS only. This editor is **Brackets**, http://brackets.io.

I think it's hard to find real-time editor when you're working with Java and Python. That programming languages need to interpret or convert into byte code first. It's something to think about. But, who knows if there exists (programming solution approach or new project/idea).

**Koding**, https://koding.com is an example (alternative) to edit your codes (real time).

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take a chance here and say that you don't care too much about your Java or Python (please correct me if I am wrong). That's the logic and you are concerned with appearance.

Take a look at [Brackets IDE](http://brackets.io/).

I only use it for AngularJS, HTML & CSS. When you make a change, it is immediately reflected in the browser without having to upload or even save a file. Great for quick "what if I change the size/colour, etc" questions.

> Live Preview
>
> Get a real-time connection to your browser. Make changes to CSS and
>   HTML and you'll instantly see those changes on screen. Also see where
>   your CSS selector is being applied in the browser by simply putting
>   your cursor on it.

Comment: This is the exact IDE I thought of when reading the question.

Comment: I don't actually have any experience with it though but read about it a few years ago and never got around to trying it out. It sounded exactly like what @keith is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/):

- free and open source
- FTP support (also [SFTP](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3590/903)): it uploads whenever you save your code
- Windows, Mac OS and Linux
- PHP, HTML, CSS, Javascript, Python,Java  (and a huge amount of other languages)

Comment: You don't mention the prime requirement the OP mentions, namely previewing the code without having to upload it to a server.

Comment: @Seth OP asked "can edit my code and see the changes as I go. Is there any such program? Uploading the rewritten code to a web server every time is a pain." IMHO auto-upload to FTP is a solution, unless uploading is a pain due to connection speed. (I guessed that it was a pain because he was doing this manually)

Comment: Auto-uploading then wouldn't really solve the problem, would it? I guess I see what you mean, although, IMHO, that is hardly a solution.

Comment: If uploading is a pain because he was doing this manually (which quite a few people do) then that'b a solution. Some ambiguity, I agree

Answer (score 0):

I support @Mawg's answer but alternatively you can connect an IDE like Sublime Text to the files on your server and while you edit them and save they are updated on the server. You don't have to move them back and forth. You could do this with any IDE that can open an ssh connection to a server or you could also mount your server like sftp and open files directly from your mount.

That would still require a hard refresh each time you look at your work in the browser but really that's just cmd/ctrl+r or whatever.

Finally, if you're working a specific day on just your HTML/CSS/JS then you can use Chrome DevTools and it works pretty well. There are even plugins that will track your changes in DevTools and allow you to save them to the file. Used in conjunction with the sftp above you could be using DevTools to update your browser and server at the same time. This wouldn't work for your backend code though and just useful if one-off you just needed to do HTML/CSS/JS.

Edit: Just read @Franck's answer and he's saying the same thing but for Eclipse. Essentially the moral of the story is you can connect your IDE to your server files and not have to worry about uploading and you can do this with quite a few IDE's like Sublime and Eclipse Franck mentioned.