# Eclipse plugin to auto-upload a file to an SFTP server on save

Tags: windows, programming, eclipse, sftp

I am looking for an Eclipse plug-in that can automatically upload a file whenever the file is saved. The file should be saved on my machine, then uploaded to the server (i.e. I don't want to edit the file on the server directly, as I could do with the [Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime Eclipse plugin](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3599/903).). It should work on Windows. Ideally it should be easy to turn on and off the plug-in.

Comment: Did you find any solution ? I got the same problem.

Comment: @Loenix I haven't found any solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've ever found that works well is installing the Aptana plugin. After it installs open the app explorer window. Click on the box icon and click run web deployment wizard. I have it setup to sync just one way to the server. After you set it up it'll try to sync to the server. You can just cancel that out. It should now upload on save. Hope this helps.